# assigning all properties of object of base class to derived one

Tags: c++

I have derived class D from base class B, like follow:

```
class D : public B
{
//staff or nothing
}
```

I want to process received pointer `B* b`, in a way that declare 
`D* d`, and initialize `*d`  with all same property values from `*b`.
What is possible or best way to do it, if i have no rights to change `B` implementation?
Something like

```
// I have pointer to B object, B* b received as a result of some function
class D : public B
{
//staff or nothing
}
D *d; //declaration 
// I want to initialize d, something like d=b (if that would be legal)
// or d = static_cast <D*>(b);
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500147/copy-constructors-and-base-classes-c

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please express it using (pseudo)code.

Comment: you'll need constructor D::D(const B &b);

Comment: Yes, thank you, but please,does it mean that I need to know all properties from B?

Comment: You cannot (are not allowed by the language) to do that automatically. Example: If this was possible, and you use `d` to access a property that is not part of the `b` object, what is supposed to happen? Those properties are not initialized and their memory location might be outside the `b` object. Therefore you need to create a `d` object and copy/move the data from b to d. You'll need to add a constructor in class D like tp1 said. They reverse, `B* b = new D;` is allowed without requiring an explicit constructor in B, since an object of type D has all properties of an object of type B.

Comment: Answering your question in your comment: In the copy constructor tp1 suggested, you can invoke the copy (implicit) constructor of the `B` class `D::D(B const& b) : B(b) {/*...*/}`. So you do not have to write down the code to copy each property (data member).

Answer (score 1):

### Basic answer

**Notation:**

```
B b;
B* pb = &b;
D* pd;
```

If you have the pointer `pb` and want to have a pointer `pd`, where `*pd` has the same (values of) data members as `*pb`, then you have to copy or move the data from `*pb` to some (memory) location and let `pd` point to that location.

C++ does not allow a conversion from `&b` to `pd` neither implicit (`pd = &b`) nor explicit (`pd = static_cast<D*>(&b)`) without resulting in undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour is as bad as it can get, as you don't have any guarantees what will happen next (crash, data corruptions, heisenbugs, ..).

---

### About `static_cast` ptr conversions

Let's introduce some naming from the Standard to make things more clear:

```
B* pb = &d;
```

Then the *static type* of `*pb` is `B` whereas the *dynamic type* of `*pb` is `D`. Static type is basically what the compiler sees, and dynamic type is what is actually in there at run time.

The following conversion is fine:

```
D d;
pb = &d;  // `pb` points to `B`-type subobject of `d`
pd = static_cast<D*>(pb);  // reverts the cast above to get the original `&d`
```

The last line is fine in case `*pb` has the dynamic type `D` (or a derived type of `D`). Else, undefined behaviour. That is why there's `dynamic_cast`:

```
pd = dynamic_cast<D*>(pb);
```

Again, if `*pb` is of dynamic type `D`, everything is fine (same as above). But if `*pb` is not of dynamic type `D`, `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer value (`nullptr`). This way, no undefined behaviour, you can check whether `pd` is `nullptr` now or not. As `dynamic_cast` is substantially slower than `static_cast`, if you *really know* that the conversion will succeed, you can use `static_cast` instead ([see the Qt example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#eventFilter)).

---

### Copy or move the data to a new object

Now what if you want to have a pointer `pd` such that all data members ("properties") are the same as the data members of `&b`?
You have to create an object of type `D` and copy or move the data from `&b` to this new object. This is what Subaru Tashiro's proposed in Method 2, like:

```
class D : public B
{
public:
    // copy:
    D(B const& b) : B(b) {} // if you cannot use B-copy-ctor than have to provide own definition
    // move:
    D(B&& b) : B(b) {} // same issue as above
};

B b;
B* pb = &b;

D d1(*pb);  // this is how you can copy
D d2( std::move(*pb) );  // this is how you can move

D* pd = &d1; // or = &d2;
```

Note both the copy and move line create a new `D`-type object to store the copied/moved data in. You don't need to provide both copy and move support.

There are other possibilities like wrapping the `B`-type object, but they differ from your approach of a derived class.

---

### Some remarks why the conversion `pd = &b` is bad

- First of all, Subaru Tashiro is right in that the data members that have been introduced with the `D` child class are problematic. If the `D` class adds any data members, how should C++ / the compiler know how they should be initialized? It cannot just leave them uninitialized as this would be error prone (consider class invariants).
- Memory problems. Example: Imagine a `D`-type object would look like this in memory:

  ```
  |DD[BBBB]DDDDDDDD|
      ^start of B sub-object
   ^start of D object
  ```

  Now, when you do `pd = static_cast<D*>(pb)`, the address contained in `pb` would be interpreted as *start of B sub-object* and be decreased by 2 bytes to get the *start of D object*.

  - As you have only allocated the space for the `b` object, it's only guaranteed you can access the memory from `(char*)pb` to `(char*)pb + sizeof(b)` (w/o considering alignment inside `b`). It could be possible that accessing the memory before `(char*)pb` or after `(char*)pb + sizeof(b)` leads to an error, e.g. the CPU complaining about you accessing virtual memory that has not been mapped to physical memory. It's more probable that there's other meaningful data before `(char*)pb` and after `(char*)pb + sizeof(b)`. By writing to any data member of `static_cast<D*>(pb)` that has been introduced in the `D` class, you can corrupt this other data (not sure about the other data members).
  - You can get alignment issues when accessing any members via `*pd`, e.g. if your compiler assumes all D-type objects start at a 2-byte boundary and all B-type objects start at a 4-byte boundary (tricky and pathologic, but a possible problem).
- If there's a vtable in `D`, it won't be initialized by the pointer conversion. Calling any virtual method of `static_cast<D*>(pb)` that has been introduced in the `D` class is therefore not a good idea.
- RTTI might as well give you problems, since it can be implemented by storing the RTT info alongside the object. RTTI can be used in exceptions and `dynamic_casts`, so it's not only `typeid` that's affected.
- The C++ Standard says, this conversion leads to undefined behaviour. That is, even if you can use the `B` sub-object of `*pd` with some compilers / C++ implementations w/o problems, there's no guarantee it will work with all compilers / versions. The points above are some of the problems that came to my mind, but I'm by no means an expert. Essentially, *there's no way to predict / no guarantee what will happen when you perform this conversion and use the `B` sub-object of the resulting `pd`*.

Final remarks:

- `static_cast` reference for this: 5.2.9/2, last 2 sentences
- My answer differs from Subaru Tashiro's in that I'd "comdemn" the first method. You can write it down and it's a well-formed program (that means, it should compile), but you cannot predict what will happen and it's a hack (may work, but not to be repeated elsewhere, bad style, ....). If you really want to do this, I'd rather suggest using a `reinterpret_cast` and a lot of comments around this to indicate you know what you're doing right there and that it is a hack.

Comment: Actually you've explained it quite well. I understand now. Basically you cannot convert a pointer of type B to a pointer of type D because only the object of type B is allocated in memory. So in other words it may or may not work. Question: is it possible to convert an object of type B into an object of type D? Or does static_cast only work with pointers? Anyway, make this answer a bit simpler and complete on it's own. I'm going to vote this up.

Comment: @SubaruTashiro It is allowed for `static_cast` to convert an object `d` to an object `b` *if* you have provided a (explicit) conversion operator (ctor) in `D`, like `explicit D(B const&)`. It is not allowed if there's no such conversion operator, as e.g. the `D` class may use class invariants that would require an initialization of additional data members.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
You can use `static_cast` to use a base class to initialize a derived class but this will result in an incomplete derived object.

[source](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

> static_cast can perform conversions between pointers to related classes, not only from the derived class to its base, but also from a base class to its derived. This ensures that at least the classes are compatible if the proper object is converted, but no safety check is performed during runtime to check if the object being converted is in fact a full object of the destination type. Therefore, it is up to the programmer to ensure that the conversion is safe.

See this example:

here we write the base class that has a public variable called "bInt"

```
class B {
public:
  int bInt;
};
```

here we create a subclass that also has it's own variable called "dInt"

```
class D: public B {
public:
  int dInt;
};
```

here we have a new instance of the base class. We initialize the base object's variable.

```
B * baseObj = new B;
baseObj->bInt = 1;
```

Here we use the base class to declare and initialize the derived class by using `static_cast`. Note that at this point, `*derivedObj` is incomplete. To be specific, `derivedObj->dInt` has an undefined value.

```
D * derivedObj = static_cast<D*>(baseObj);
```

Because D is derived from B, it also has the `bInt` variable. And because we used `static_cast` to initialize `*derivedObj`, the value of it's `bInt` is also the same as `*baseObj`'s `bInt`, therefore they are equal.

```
if(baseObj->bInt == derivedObj->bInt)
{
  display("it's equal");
}
```

But because the base class has no `dInt` variable, this variable will be left uninitialized and the outcome of this procedure is undefined.

```
int myNum = derivedObj->dInt;
```

If you plan to use static_cast, be sure to initialize members of the derived class. It's a good habit to do so anyway.

When using static_cast, you don't need to know all of the members of B. D automatically has all of B's member values. But what you're trying to do is dangerous because you are creating an incomplete object.

**Method 2:** If you really need to subclass B, then write D's constructor as one that takes a B* and initializes it's B by copying like so:

```
D(const B &pass) : B(pass)
```

So when you want to declare and initialize an object of type D this is how you do it.

```
B *baseObj = new B;
D *derivedObj = new D(*baseObj);
```

**So in summary, you have two choices:**

1. subclass B and use static_cast to initialize D. Make sure to initialize D's member variables.
2. subclass B and write a constructor that takes a B and passes it to B's copy constructor.

Both of these methods have the same outcome, the difference is how the program does this behind the scenes.

Unfortunately in your example, using `d=b` is 'illegal' (?) because you are trying to assign a base class to a derived class. You can only use the assignment operator the other way around such as `b=d` given that `d` is initialized.

You can also write your own assignment operator to do that but I personally don't recommend it.

Comment: For beginning thank you so much, Subaru. Of course, i think, i have good reasons to try something like this, as well as i know. I will prepare more detailed info about my task D(b) here soon, so if you have some good will, please answer

Comment: alright, I've edited my answer. I understand that you are using B's member functions inside D am I right?

Comment: So, basically, this is the task,
Let us assume that B class have some protected method pM and protected data member pDM. I need to define new methods in D class, so I can intercept b, modify b.pDM or even b.pM, and such modified object *b pass for further processing
Thanks

Comment: @SubaruTashiro: If you use `static_cast` to do something like `B b; D* pd = static_cast<D*>(&b)`, the _behaviour is undefined_ [expr.static.cast] (accessing the data members could even raise a segfault). IIRC, there can be issues with vtables and other things that can change the alignment of the `B`-type subobject in a `D`-type object. Maybe it works with PODs, but still a bad idea.

Comment: @user2212476 yes, you can do that with both methods. Why don't you try it out and if you encounter any problems just get back here and update your question.

Comment: @DyP it will not throw an exception as long as B is a base class of D and B is dynamically allocated.. But no runtime/compile time checks are made to see if B is indeed a base class of D so the programmer needs to take care of this. I guess because of that method 2 is safer because one can write a constructor that can ONLY take an object of type B. I did say that doing so is dangerous in my answer.

Comment: @SubaruTashiro AFAIK, `static_cast` doesn't throw exceptions for any pointer conversion (not just base classes / dynamic allocation). There *are* checks by the compiler to see if the conversion is possible, only looking at the static types (that is, my example compiles). Method 1 is not flawed because of possible exceptions, it is flawed because your program can *crash* without any message (or even worse) <- undefined behaviour. Even if it doesn't crash, there's no guarantee it will work in the way you described.

Comment: @DyP `static_cast` does not throw any kind of exception but it can result in undefined behavior which includes throwing an exception [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551853/can-static-cast-throw-an-exception-in-c). I just checked and the compiler does throw an error if `B` is not a base of `D`. Using `static_cast` to do something like `B b; D* pd = static_cast<D*>(&b)` will not result in undefined behavior as long as B's lifetime is longer than D's usage. And Qt uses static_cast this way to pass around events. [LINK](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#eventFilter)

Comment: @DyP and also as long as D is a complete object. Simply using static_cast will result in an incomplete D so the programmer has to take care of that.

Comment: @SubaruTashiro I'd rather like to discuss this in SO chat (but the interface is weird). Ad exception: the second (!) answer in your first link correctly states that `static_cast` (generally speaking) can throw exceptions. It does not throw an exception for these kind of conversions here. If `B` is not a base class of `D`, the progam is ill-formed (illegal), that's why your compiler "throws an error".  Ad undefined behaviour: See 5.2.9/2, last 2 sentences. The Qt example makes sure `event` is of dynamic type `QKeyEvent`.

Comment: @DyP There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my answer. If you have any objections just point it out and I will edit as necessary. SO really isn't made to be a forum so discussions like this are unnecessary. If you want you may post your own answer.

Comment: @SubaruTashiro I'd agree with you this is not a discussion fitting the SO format, so I've followed your advice and posted an answer. Essentially, you _cannot_ do this: "If you plan to use static_cast, be sure to initialize members of the derived class.", and this is not very precise / flawed: "*derivedObj is incomplete. To be specific, derivedObj->dInt has an undefined value". I find it hard to explain what I mean, though. Hope my answer helps.